# RestApi на Go и ответы на запросы из рутин

Tags: многопоточность, сервер, golang

Намедни начал изучать Go, с целью написания простого сервера. Т.к. до этого опыта написания серверных приложений нет, то хотелось бы услышать в какую сторону копать от более опытных товарищей. Идея: Rest сервер, с авторизацией, для каждого клиента как я понимаю надо открывать поток(рутину), внутри каждого будет идти запрос данных с другого места, обработка, чтение - запись в базу, и прочие вероятно долгие операции. Основной вопрос такой, как определять какая рутина какому клиенту принадлежит и как к этой определенной рутине сделать запрос на выдачу данных, при этом нужно же не блокировать основной поток. Вероятно выше написанное попахивает несусветной чушью, но повторю, с серверным программированием не имел ничего общего до этого. Заранее спасибо за советы и/или критику.

Answer (score 0):

Вот простейший пример передачи данных между горутинами. Для передачи данных используется мап айдишника на канал. Первый хендлер регистрирует айдишник и ждёт сообщения, либо вылетает по таймауту. Второй принимает айдишник и сообщение чтобы послать.

Опущены обработка ошибок и зачистка для краткости.

```golang
m := sync.Map{}
http.HandleFunc("/read", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    id := r.PostFormValue("id")
    ch := make(chan string, 1)
    m.Store(id, ch)
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(r.Context(), 10*time.Second)
    defer cancel()

    select {
    case s := <-ch:
        log.Printf("message: %q", s)
    case <-ctx.Done():
        log.Printf("error: %q", ctx.Err())
    }
})
http.HandleFunc("/write", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    id := r.PostFormValue("id")
    msg := r.PostFormValue("msg")
    ch, ok := m.Load(id)
    if !ok {
        http.NotFound(w, r)
    }

    ch.(chan string) <- msg
})
http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
```